# Unable to connect SQL express DB instance via jdbc when database password contains back slash

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to connect to SQL express DB instance via jdbc. DB password is `Passw0rd\\`. Here I have printed jdbc URL, password, and stack trace.

```
> jdbcURL:
> jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:2638;instanceName=SQLEXPRESSSYMC;integratedSecurity=false;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true,
> user: DBA password: Passw0rd\
> 
> 
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262),
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:283),
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:129),
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37),
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:5233),
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3988),
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3932),
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7375),
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3206),
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2713),
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2362),
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2213),
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1276),
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:861),
> java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677),
> java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
```

If I set database password which does not end with backslash then I am able to make jdbc connection.
Let me know how to resolve this.

Here is the code I am using:

```
  String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:2638;instanceName=SQLEXPRESSSYMC;integratedSecurity=false;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";
    String password = "Passw0rd\\";
    try
    {
        System.out.println("url:" +url );
        System.out.println("Password:"+password);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url , "DBA", password);
        System.out.println("connected");
        
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In failed case it prints following line and then exception stack:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'DBA'. ClientConnectionId:3be3d544-73d3-4710-aa4e-dfe78b6dcbb1

If I set DB password which uses back slash character but not as an end character then it works. e.g

String password = "Passw0rd\\a";

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you use to connect to SQL Server. Please also clarify whether your database password ends with one or two backslashes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.